# Couldn't match expected type ‘Term’

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to develop a `match` function to combine two Tuplas into a Record, which has the following combination [(Label, Value)]. The first Tuple, there must be only elements of type String and the second Tuple can be any other type of element.

The code is:

```
type RItem = (Label, Term)

type TItem = (Term)

type Label = String

data Term = Record [RItem]
          | Tuple [TItem]
          | B Bool
          | N Int
          | S String
        deriving(Eq, Show)  

match :: Term -> Term -> Term
match (Tuple _) (Tuple []) = Record []
match (Tuple []) (Tuple _) = Record []
match (Tuple (x:xs)) (Tuple (z:zs)) = [(x,z)] ++ match (Tuple xs) (Tuple zs)
```

However, at the time of compiling the above code, this error is shown:

[image]

An example of code that should be written and working in this program is:

```
> t1 = Tuple [(S "a"), (S "b")]
> t2 = Tuple [(N 10), (N 20)]
> match t1 t2
```

And the valid result should be a Record as follows:: `Record [("a", 10), ("b", 20)]`.

Comment: Ask yourself this: What if I did `match (Tuple [B True]) (Tuple [N 10])`? What should happen then?

Comment: You do not wrap the resulting list back in a `Term` constructor. Furhermore you perform recursion, but that recursion will yield a `Record`, so you should unwrap that record and prepend it with a value and wrap it back into a `Term` constructor.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo In this case, it should return an error because it is not part of the specifications of a Record. At the moment, I did not even validate the entries yet, because I could not get out of this error. But it is still necessary to validate the entries so that the first Tuple is only of type S (String) and also, the two Tuplets have to have the same amount of elements. After I can resolve this error, I will work on this validation.

Comment: You can't *not* validate, though. Haskell won't let you deal with invalid data, by virtue of how powerful the type system is. So you *have* to deal with the non-`S` case, even if it's just to call `error` (which happens by default if you pattern match and don't provide an alternative).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That's right, I expressed myself poorly in what I said. That's exactly what you said. Sorry for the mistake :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the information on how to solve the error, I will try to work on it. I'm still learning Haskell. It's totally new to me.

Comment: Please never paste pictures of error messages. Copy and paste the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
match (Tuple (x:xs)) (Tuple (z:zs)) = [(x,z)] ++ match (Tuple xs) (Tuple zs)
```

The result of the recursive call will be a `Term`, so you can't apply the list concatenation operator, `++`, to it. Furthermore, the result of such a concatenation would be a list, not a `Term`, so you'd end up with the wrong result type.

The underlying operation here is really just the standard

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
```

so let's build on that:

```
match (Tuple labels) (Tuple terms) = Record (zip labels terms)
```

As others have noted, this is a bit strange, because it will fail for non-`Tuple` values. So you likely want something more like

```
match2 :: [Label] -> [Term] -> Term
match2 labels values = Record (zip labels values)
```

But this still seems surprising, because it doesn't seem to make much sense to build a record from label and value lists of different lengths. Perhaps you could use

```
match3 :: [Label] -> [Term] -> Maybe Term
match3 ls ts = Record <$> zipSame ls ts

zipSame :: [a] -> [b] -> Maybe [(a,b)]
zipSame [] [] = Just []
zipSame (l:ls) (t:ts) = ((l,t):) <$> zipSame ls ts
zipSame _ _ = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you. I really was having a hard time resolving this issue. Your solution was perfect.

Comment: If possible, I would like you to clarify a question about the <$> operator in the third line of zipSame. The use of this operator is new to me, because I did not know it before. What's the difference to just using $ and <$>?

Comment: @LeomardeSouza, `<$>` is an infix version of `fmap`. I'm mapping over the `Maybe` to apply a function to whatever (if anything) is inside. In this context, it is used with type `(<$>) :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`, but it actually works for any `Functor`.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a `Term` but in order to return the type you want, you need it to be a `Label`. So you need to pattern match on the label.

```
match (Tuple (S x : xs)) (Tuple (z : zs)) = [(x, z)] ++ match (Tuple xs) (Tuple zs)
```

But this raises the question: what if I pass `match (Tuple [B True]) (Tuple [N 10])`? We can't, according to your types, define a `Record` with a Boolean for a key. So should the program crash? Or should we get some "default" behavior? You might consider changing match so that it takes `[Label]` as its first argument, rather than a general `Term`. This eliminates the need to do all this pattern matching, so it's clearer, and it stops people from being able to pass nonsense data to it, so it's more correct.

If for some reason you need people to be able to pass a general `Term` to `match`, you might consider returning a `Maybe` so you can gracefully handle the failure case.

Comment: Imho, this does not really answers the question what is wrong with the code. It provides some good suggestions about improving it, but does not point to the error that the OP aims to solve.